# reserving a place for a radiobutton created dynamically in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I am creating radiobuttons positioned horizontally, I am showing some  and not showing others depending on some condition

If i set visible to false, the place will be occupied by the  next radio button,
 is there any way of put space instead?

basic creation of radiobutton: (TEST only code)

```
                    Dim rdButton As New RadioButton
                    rdButton.Text = "test"
                    rdButton.GroupName = "test2"
                    cell.Controls.Add(rdButton)
                    Dim rdButton2 As New RadioButton
                    rdButton2.Text = "test2"
                    rdButton2.GroupName = "test2"
                    rdButton2.Visible=False
                    cell.Controls.Add(rdButton2) 
                    Dim rdButton3 As New RadioButton
                    rdButton3.Text = "test"
                    rdButton3.GroupName = "test2"
                    cell.Controls.Add(rdButton3)
```

thanks

Comment: they are positioned horizontally

Comment: Sorry. I have changed this to reflect horizontal layout. Please check the '[test](http://jsfiddle.net/xh9XN/3/)' link again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use CSS Class to hide the radio button. To achieve this you can do something similar to this:

**Css:**

```
.radio-spacer {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

**ASP.Net Controls:**

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" Text="Blue" GroupName="Hats"
 runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton CssClass="radio-spacer" ID="RadioButton2" Text="Purple" 
 GroupName="Hats" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" Text="Orange" GroupName="Hats"
 runat="server" />
```

**or Alternative (just Html):**

```
<label>
<input type="radio" name="hatColour" value="blue" id="hatColour_0" />
Blue</label>
<label class="radio-spacer">
<input type="radio" name="hatColour" value="purple" id="hatColour_0" />
Purple</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="hatColour" value="orange" id="hatColour_1" />
Orange</label>
```

In the above example you will see 2 radio buttons (Blue and Orange) and you will see a spacer where Purple should be. You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xh9XN/3/).

Comment: they are positioned horizontally

Comment: I changed to radiobuttonlist, and this worked perfectly: rdBtnList.Items.FindByText(lstItem.Text).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("visibility", "hidden") but the below works but there will not be an empty space: rdBtnList.Items.FindByText(lstItem.Text).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none")

Comment: Thats exactly how the CSS `visibility` and `display` are supposed to work. `display` does not draw the bounds of the object, whereas `visibility` still draws the bounds of the object.